# Swift Not Recognizing Firebase Users

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, core-location

I am very new to coding and trying to learn how to get my user information from Firebase!

I have recently added code to get longitude and latitude coordinates from firebase. Unfortunately, I no longer can see the users in the view controller when I run the app. Before adding the code the users would show up perfectly.`

```
func retrieveUsers(){
    //this is where you will also have to call the users location
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let users = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        self.user.removeAll()
        for (_,value) in users {
            if let uid = value["uid"] as? String {
                if uid != Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
                    let userToShow = User()
                    if let fullName = value["full name"] as? String, let imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String
                        ,let userLongitude = value["long"] as? String, let userLatitude = value["lat"] as? String
                        //for some reason adding this makes it impossible to get code
                        //userLongitude and userLatitude cause no users to show up


                    {
                        userToShow.fullName = fullName
                        userToShow.imagePath = imagePath
                        userToShow.userID = uid
                        userToShow.userLongitude = userLongitude
                        userToShow.userLatitude = userLatitude

                        self.user.append(userToShow)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    })

    ref.removeAllObservers()

}
`
```

Here is more code correlated to this problem:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = self.user[indexPath.row].fullName
    cell.userID = self.user[indexPath.row].userID
    cell.userImage.downloadImage(from: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)
    cell.longLabel.text = self.user[indexPath.row].userLongitude
    cell.latLabel.text = self.user[indexPath.row].userLatitude
    //I believe that you need to go to userCell and define these variables


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please add this statement `print(self.user)`  before `self.tableview.reloadData()` and check what does it print?

Comment: It did not print anything.

Comment: Can you please show the structure of your firebase db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make two changes :

Replace

```
self.tableview.reloadData()
```

with

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Since you are making a change to UI, so you should run it on the main thread.

And second I think You should remove observers in `viewDidDisappear`, so remove this line `ref.removeAllObservers()` from the above code.

Another problem I can see is this code:

```
 if let fullName = value["full name"] as? String, let imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String
                        ,let userLongitude = value["long"] as? String, let userLatitude = value["lat"] as? String
                        //for some reason adding this makes it impossible to get code
                        //userLongitude and userLatitude cause no users to show up


                    {
                        userToShow.fullName = fullName
                        userToShow.imagePath = imagePath
                        userToShow.userID = uid
                        userToShow.userLongitude = userLongitude
                        userToShow.userLatitude = userLatitude

                        self.user.append(userToShow)
                    }
```

Here if anyone of the value is not available, that will not populate the user at all, instead you should populate them one by one:

```
userToShow.fullName = value["full name"] as? String
userToShow.imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String
...
```

Comment: @BeccaD please check the updated answer see if it helps you

Comment: @BeccaD comment the `if` statement for now, and try setting the values one by one

Comment: I ended up having to delete all of the users in firebase to make it work. Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

1) Calling retrieve user function in View First Load as its ObserveSingleEvent so it will Observe and Run just once not as Handler like observe

2) Remove delegate and datasource of tableView from StoryBoard and the time you are reloading table Provide here as like

```
self.tableview.datasource = self
self.tableview.delegate = self
self.tableview.reloadData()
```

3) Handler run Asynchronously so Reload table View after handler is executed so use a dispatch Queue

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.tableview.datasource = self
   self.tableview.delegate = self
   self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Note if after following Steps data is still empty no users popped up in table

1) Try printing value of User that is being added to usersArray

2) And when you reload tableView in `numbersOfItemInSection` also print array here to check data is being passed to tableView or not.

3) if array is with values in `numbersOfItemInSection` then check user cell class used for cell , reconnect outlets there